# How to reproduce an area of cells on another worksheets automatically?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know how to automatically copy an area of cells of Worksheet 1 to Worksheet 2

Explanation :

Worksheet 1 is the proposition phase, we only put the product, localization, and price.

Worksheet 2 is the contract phase where the customers sign, so there is all Worksheet 1 information plus the legal information.

[image: The proposition view]

Everything between the orange line (13) and the last line where there is written “TOTAL H.T” need to be reproduced to the contract.

[image: Contract view]

So you see that there is the second page made for this.

My idea:

I wanted to make a simple Copy and PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats with the designated area, but the problem is that every contract is different.

Now I need to find a way to select everything between A13:I13 and the line where there is “TOTAL H.T” written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing that you mean there is a variable number of rows between 13 and "TOTAL H.T"

Anyway, heres the code:

```
Sub Copy_Paste()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet: Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet: Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim last_row As Integer: last_row = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(13, 1), sht1.Cells(last_row, 9))
    
    rng.Copy (sht2.Range("I1"))

End Sub
```

Comment: The last line didnt work so i changed it

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer :

```
Sub Copy_Paste()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet: Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet: Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim last_row As Integer: last_row = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(13, 1), sht1.Cells(last_row, 9))
    
    rng.Copy
    sht2.Range("I52").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sht2.Range("I52").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats


End Sub
```

So there is the same format !

Thanks to the team.